# Class global variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create variables that can be accessed from any class coming from a Java background I'm struggling to understand this in Objective-C..

in Java we have:

```
public static int MAIN_MENU = 1, SELECTION_SCREEN = 2;
```

These can be accessed anywhere like so:

```
ClassName.MAIN_MENU;
```

How would do achieve the same thing in its simplest form for Objective-C keeping it within a class?

Comment: In languages based on C (C, C++, ObjC), you'd typically use an enum rather than a bunch of global variables.

Comment: By the way, there are no global variables in Java. There are *static attributes on classes*.

Comment: @Sulthan: Don't kid yourself; `static` is just how Java spells "global".   `com.whatever.MyClass.FOO` always semantically refers to the same named storage location wherever it is visible...and if it's public, it's visible everywhere.  That is pretty much the very definition of a global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Objective-C, classes have no static members. The best I can imagine is creating a getter and setter class method with an utterly ugly global variable:

```
static T _member = initialValue;

+ (T)someStaticMember
{
    return _member;
}

+ (void)setSomeStaticMember:(T)newVal
{
    _member = newVal;
}
```

If you only need a getter, i. e. emulation of a read-only member, then move the static variable inside the function, at least you will have one less global that way.

---

**BUT:** if you only need integer constants, why not use an `enum`? Or at least some macros?

Comment: @OllyDixon You mean Objective-C? It surely gets some time to get used to it. But really, calling out on a language being bad because you don't know how to implement enums... that's a bit of an exaggeration.

Comment: @OllyDixon For example?

Comment: Header files, Declaring methods twice, It's not neat at all, allocating and deallocation, doesn't follow standard dot (.) class rule which makes things hard to read n lots more.

Comment: v@OllyDixon Hm. Header files are a C heritage, and they have design decisions behind them. Declaring twice? Nah. You declare once, and then write the **definition.** Any statically-typed compiled language needs this. You seem to think that these languages are inferior to "nice and productive" slow dynamic languages. What's wrong with allocation and deallocation? How else do you think memory management ought to be done? And what's all with the "standard" (what standard?) dot rule? You can use the dot notation to access properties in Objective-C...

Comment: There's no reason you should use static variables, but i understand you, you've designed something for java and want to port it to objc now.

Comment: @OllyDixon After 2 years with Obj-C I can say it's a pretty nice language. What you see as standard, is taken directly from C++ (predecessor of Java, C# and others). Well, Obj-C doesn't have C++ as its predecessor because both languages evolved simultaneously. You should see some more extreme Java-unlike languages, like Prolog or LISP.

Comment: I'll check them out, out of interest.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is use static variable only inside the own class you could declare your variable in `.m` file otherwise you must define a global constant using `#define`.

`#define CONSTANT [ any value ]`

Comment: Can you give an example of how I'd use #define?

Comment: @OllyDixon Please google "C preprocessor macros". If you don't know them, you should be learning C yet instead of jumping straight into Objective-C.

Comment: I don't have time for that, already started making the menu screens using OpenGL :-P

Comment: That's curious, how are you gonna write opengl without knowing some very basic things? You put this in the header '#define MAIN_MENU 1' then you use MAIN_MENU as you've used in java. You need to import the header wherever you want to use it of course. Note that this is not a static variable, you cannot change it at runtime, the compiler will inline the value so you get also some speed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should to use `#define MAIN_MENU 1` in header file.
2. You should to use `NSInteger const MAIN_MENU = 1;` in m-file and `extern NSInteger const MAIN_MENU;` in h-file.

And `#import` this header-file to class you want to use MAIN_MENU